# failure deploying LocalDB app to Arvixe

Tags: c#, iis, deployment, connection-string, localdb

I'm trying to deploy a WCF Data Service to Arvixe. The data service is built on Entity Framework 5 and Data Services 5.4. It creates a fair number of LocalDB databases (named according to runtime input) and runs fine locally. There is no connection string in the web.config. The DB names are passed to the DbContext constructor. However, when I deploy my project to my Arvixe (Windows) account, I get this error (below). The error doesn't make sense because there isn't any connection string. And if it writes any information to a log file, I don't have access to it. It's not in my standard IIS log that shows up in the logs folder next to wwwroot. I could put in a connection string. What is an example of a localDB connection string that has a "TBD" for the database name?

```
The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:

at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection) at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest) at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ForceOSpaceLoadingForKnownEntityTypes() at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext() at lambda_method(Closure , Object ) at System.Data.Services.Providers.DbContextHelper.GetObjectContext(Object o) at System.Data.Services.Caching.MetadataCache`1.TryLookup(Type serviceType, Object dataContextInstance) at System.Data.Services.Providers.BaseServiceProvider.LoadMetadata() at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateMetadataAndQueryProviders(IDataServiceMetadataProvider& metadataProviderInstance, IDataServiceQueryProvider& queryProviderInstance, BaseServiceProvider& builtInProvider, Object& dataSourceInstance) at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateProvider() at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest() at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessRequestForMessage(Stream messageBody) at SyncInvokeProcessRequestForMessage(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Comment: Do you have a ticket number for your issue? Arvixe's Support team would be able to assist you with an issue like this. If you e-mail QA[@]Arvixe.com they will be sure to get you some assistance. Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two weeks of email trips with Arvixe, they informed me that the cannot install LocalDb on my shared server; I need their VPS account instead. That's unfortunate. The person who told me that it was installed originally was misinformed.

Answer (score 1):

These connection strings should work for the account:

https://support.arvixe.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/51/8/do-you-have-a-connection-string-i-can-use-to-connect-to-the-local-mssql-database

You'd just need to change the information per your needs.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate the link. However, "local database" and "LocalDb" in this particular case are not quite the same thing. That link shows how to connect to SQL Server Express, but not the new SQL Server Express 2012 LocalDB stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Where is LocalDB located? Do note that since our newest servers do not run SQL Server Express, you can simply use localhost or server.arvixe.com where server is the name of the server you are on.

Lastly, even though you may not be using a connection string, however way you are specifying to connect within your code is considered the "connection string". So, it doesn't neces

Comment: When I run locally without specifying any particular location, my LocalDB files are automatically created in the App_Data folder of my project. I expected them to be automatically put in the data folder next to wwwroot when running it on the web server.